# How does an LG 4K monitor support 3008x1692 resolution but a 5k Apple Studio display does not?

Tags: display, resolution

The LG 27UL850-W monitor has native resolution of 4K 3840x2160 but also offers 3K 3008x1692 which looks very crisp and is a ratio of 60:47 ie not a simple ratio.

The Apple Studio display which is 5120x2880, does not support 3840x2160. The closest option is 2560x1440, a ratio of 2:1.

How/why can the LG monitor do this scaling and look great but the apple display can't?

In this configuration, it seems like the LG is somehow presenting a virtual 6K 6016x384 resolution to the Operating System which then scales it in a 2:1 ratio. See screenshot.

Is this a hardware feature of the LG monitor that the Apple monitor just hasn't implemented?

[image: LG Scaling Options and Hardware Info]

Comment: Without having an LG monitor to test with, have you tried something like BetterDisplay? https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay

Comment: I tried SwitchResX and it technically it was able to change the Studio Display to use 3008x1692, but everything looked very blurry, like when you enable "Show all resolutions" and select one of the "low resolution" options in the MacOS display settings.

Comment: Try BetterDisplay. It is better than SwitchResX in my opinion. On my 27" iMac (5120x2880), I can set 3008x1692.  Looks very crisp. Text is a bit small for me.

Comment: It is macOS which creates the 2x 6016x3384 virtual display which is then autoscaled (by macOS) to the LG's physical display.  Sort of opposite to your thinking.